# How to use QAxWidget browser to open url with WebGl content

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, webgl, qaxwidget

I'm using QT 5.8 and trying to load webpage using QAxWidget (set to IE) that displays HTML 5 empty canvas.

```
QString url = "https://h3manth.com/demo/canvas/full-page.html";
ui.browser->dynamicCall("Navigate(const QString&)", url);
```

Running the same url directly in IE works fine.
But when running it from my simple QT application I'm getting script error:

[image]

And getting the blank view as a result even when pressing 'Yes' in the dialog.

Any ideas for possible solution?

Comment: Please post a complete minimum example to demonstrate what's going on. Put everything into a single `main.cpp` file, and edit the question to include that.

Comment: try logging out the user agent string, I'm assuming that 'IE' uses some old IE version on your system.

Comment: Any particular reason of using IE with QAxWidget instead of QWebEngineView ?

Comment: @LJᛃ - thanks I will try user agent string and post results here.

Comment: @KamilKlimek - QT WebEngine takes 400MB of RAM when running on 4K monitor in full screen mode and displaying only empty canvas (I tested by opening this url: "https://h3manth.com/demo/canvas/full-page.html"). That's way too much.

Comment: @LJᛃ Printing the web agent reveled that embedded IE was really old (Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E))

I also found the solution how to make sure IE 11 is used instead, it has to be done by modifying the reg keys:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx

So after setting the right reg keys, restarting the machine everything was working fine and the user agent reported:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Comment: @KamilKlimek, I exaggerated the memory consumption by QTWebEngine. So it was not 400MB on 4K monitor when opening (https://h3manth.com/demo/canvas/full-page.html)
It was 207MB for the simple app that was only using the QTWebEngine and  14MB for the qt webengine process.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the reg keys as described on msdn: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).asp ensures using the intended IE version for "embedded" browser